# preg_match_all and list from php to java

Tags: java, php, list, preg-match-all

I'm converting a script from php to java but i can't find a way to convert this part

```
exec('free -mo', $out); <-- Converted
preg_match_all('/\s+([0-9]+)/', $out[1], $matches);
list($total, $used, $free, $shared, $buffers, $cached) = $matches[1];
```

The exec result is this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by myself

```
        String info = cmdExec("cat /proc/meminfo");
        info = info.replaceAll(" ", "");
        info = info.replaceAll("kB", "");
        String[] lines = info.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        df = new DecimalFormat("0");
        Integer MemTot = Integer.parseInt(df.format(Integer.parseInt(lines[0].substring(lines[0].indexOf(":") + 1)) / 1024.0f));
        Integer MemFree = Integer.parseInt(df.format(Integer.parseInt(lines[1].substring(lines[1].indexOf(":") + 1)) / 1024.0f));
        Integer Buffers = Integer.parseInt(df.format(Integer.parseInt(lines[2].substring(lines[2].indexOf(":") + 1)) / 1024.0f));
        Integer Cached = Integer.parseInt(df.format(Integer.parseInt(lines[3].substring(lines[3].indexOf(":") + 1)) / 1024.0f));
        Integer Used = MemTot - MemFree;
        Integer fMemFree = MemFree + Buffers + Cached;
        Integer MemUsed = Used - Buffers - Cached;
```